# sending data using AJAX in Cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

```
   $.ajax({
  url : "../update_request",
  type : "GET",
  data : {reqdata, reqdata},
  success : function(data)
  {        
   window.location = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => '', 'action' => '')); ?>"; 
  } 
});
```

here reqdata is a string value.
when use this it display error like

> SyntaxError: invalid object initializer

in this line `data : {reqdata, reqdata}`

i also try with `data : {reqdata : reqdata}` but it not resolve.
so please help me.

Comment: Check out [CakePHP and AJAX](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/). It contains working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a key for your Data parameter, e.g.

```
'data':{keyname:value, keyname:value}
```

which gives your Data array a name keyname by which you can access it on the server.